# Safari font bug with TeX4ht

Tags: multicol, enumitem, tex4ht

I have the following TeX4ht issue: If the document contains a multicolumn list and I open the resulting HTML file in Safari, then some of the items in the list are not showing. For example, look at items 11 and 12 here:

[image: Multicolumn list with missing items]

This does not occur in any other browser I have tested. Peculiarly, if I either zoom in or out in Safari, the missing items appear again.

I am using version 15.1 (17612.2.9.1.20) of Safari. To reproduce the bug, here is `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[
    before = {
        \raggedcolumns
        \begin{multicols}{4}
    },
    after = \end{multicols}
]
    \item
    $\frac{1}{4}$    
    \item
    $\frac{1}{5}$ 
    \item
    $\frac{3}{4}$   
    \item
    $\frac{3}{5}$   
    \item
    $\frac{2}{5}$
    \item
    $\frac{4}{5}$   
    \item
    $\frac{1}{3}$
    \item
    $\frac{2}{3}$
    \item
    $\frac{32}{48}$
    \item
    $\frac{1}{40}$
    \item
    $\frac{30}{45}$ 
    \item
    $\frac{9}{2}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And `config.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html,mathml}

\Configure{@HEAD}{
    \HCode{
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,600&display=swap">
    }
}

\begin{document}

\Css{
    body {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
}

\EndPreamble
```

I compile the document with the command

```
htlatex mwe.tex "config,mathjax,charset=utf-8" " -cmozhtf -utf8";
```

Note that this is not an issue if I use the default font. Is there a way to fix this bug and keep the font Poppins?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment about the Safari issue, as I don't have access to any Apple device. This can be either bug in Safari, wrong CSS produced by TeX4ht, or a MathJax issue.

What I can tell is that there is a slight issue with the generated HTML file, caused by your use of `multicols` environment in `enumitem`. It seems that it prevents inserting of closing tags for the `enumitem` environment. This can be fixed with the following version of `enumitem.4ht`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% enumitem.4ht                       2022-04-29-17:02 %
% Copyright (C) 2009-2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/end}{\ifx\enit@after\@empty\else%
  \let\enit:after\enit@after
  \let\enit@after\@empty
  \let\enumerate:executed\@empty
  \append:def\end:DL{\enit:after}
\fi}

\Hinput{enumitem}
\endinput
```

It executes the `after` code only after the `enumitem` environment is closed. It should result in the correct closing of tags.

It seems that there is also spurious space before first element in the first column. This can be fixed using CSS:

```
\Preamble{html,mathml}

\Configure{@HEAD}{
    \HCode{
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,600&display=swap">
    }
}

\begin{document}

\Css{
    body {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .columns-4 :first-child{margin-top:0;}
}

\EndPreamble
```

With these changes, you get wildly different results in various browsers:

Firefox:

[image]

It is almost good, except for the vertical bars.

Chromium:

[image]

Quite a mess. It seems that it breaks columns incorrectly.

Qutebrowser:

[image]

Similar to Chromium, but at least it doesn't break numbers in the middle.

If anybody can suggest CSS that will work correctly in all browsers, I will happily update TeX4ht sources.