# tex4ht and the multicol package

Tags: multicol, tex4ht

The combination `make4ht` and the `multicol` package seems to be not working together. If I compile

```
%% mwe-listen.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\mytext}{This is some text for testing the listings.}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol, blindtext}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
%
\begin{enumerate}
\item \mytext
\item \mytext
\end{enumerate}
%
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

with `make4t mwe-listen` then I get no break before 1 or 2 of the list [image: Safari image] (by the way, with Firefox it is the same). Commenting out `\begin{multicols}`, then everything is working fine. I am running `OS X 12.6` and `texlive2022` last update.

Remark: I have seen the question `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642439/safari-font-bug-with-tex4ht` but it seems that there is still no solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is caused by this configuration in `html4.4ht`:

```
\ConfigureEnv{multicols}{}{}{}{}
```

It seems that it resets configurations for any list environment that is placed inside `multicols`. To fix that, it is necessary to remove this line from `html4.4ht`. I will do that, so it should be available in TeX Live update soon. After that, you should get this result:

[image]

Comment: It is working!! Great.

Comment: @michal.h21Just a additional question: How can I chance the behaviour of the numbering, i.e. the `1.` is very far away from the text. Compiling with `pdflatex` it looks different, i.e. `1. This is ..`?

Comment: @Ulrich the space is configured using CSS, so you can change it in the configuration file. Try `\Css{dl.enumerate-enumitem{display:grid; grid-template-columns: 0px 1fr; align-items: top; row-gap:1ch;}}`. This seems to be the smallest possible gap.

Comment: Thank you. I did it "by hand" in the `css`-file generated by `make4ht`. Will check, how to do this automatically.

Comment: @Ulrich you can put the code you want in CSS file to the config file: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#document-styling-using-css